# How to pass data from child to parent component in Angular6 when parent component not using child's component selector?

Tags: angular, angular6

I am adding a child component to a parent component dynamically using `ViewContainerRef` so not using child selector in parent selector template or in html.

How to pass data from child to parent component in this case?

Comment: You can do that using EventEmitter, do you need example for that?

Answer (score 0):

So basically let's suppose that you have:

### Child component

```
export class ChildComponent {
   ...
   outputData: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
   ...

   triggerChange() {
      // here you just emit some data using event emitter
      this.outputData.emit(someData);
   }
}
```

Then in parent component you can access data from EventEmitter like:

### Parent component

```
export class ParentComponent {

   attachChild() {
      ...
      let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
      (<ChildComponent>componentRef.instance).outputData.subscribe(this.outputData.bind(this));
   }

   onDataChange(someData) {
      // here you can access child's data when event emitter triggers
      // so basically it's the same if you subscribed on @Output field from template like (outputData)="onDataChange($event)"
      console.log(someData);
   }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This doesn't work. Where does the second *outputData* come from? Is it from the child component or from the parent? Also ViewContainerRef doesn't have createComponent property